# Parse XML Libxmljs (Node.js)

Tags: xml, node.js, libxml2, xml-parsing

I'm attempting to parse an XML string with [libxmljs (https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs)](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs). I'm having some issues though. I need to apply logic to what I'm parsing and return based upon what's defined and what isn't. Because of this I don't see a SAX-style parser being a valid option.

I'm willing to look at other alternatives if I can achieve what I'm looking for. Being able to select elements like DOMParser `xmlDoc.getElementsById('firstName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` would be awesome...

Comment: I guess the README does focus on the sax parsing.  Most people use the DOM stuff though.  I'll update it to make it clear that DOM is possible and give examples.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

libxmljs supports DOM as well as SAX style parsing.

```
var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXmlString('<item><data id="firstName">Your Name</data></item>');
var xmlDoc2 = libxmljs.parseXmlFile('mydata.xml');
```

The API is custom and doesn't follow the W3C/browser spec (it's on my list).  You will want to use xpath to query the document for the content you want.

```
xmlDoc.find("//[@id='firstName']")[0].childNodes()[0].text()
```

Notice that childNodes and text are function calls.  Take a look at the docs.

https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Element

As far as I know, libxmljs and jsdom are the two libraries that have decent DOM implementations.