# is it possible to request a url and parse the html content in nodejs using a DOM manipulation tool like DOMDocument in php?

Tags: dom, node.js

is it possible to request a url and parse the html response in nodejs using a DOM manipulation tool like DOMDocument in php?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190952/parse-xml-libxmljs-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) (also good article [here](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs))

Comment: Put some more effort into it!

Comment: how to import jsdom on our webpage, do we really need to import files physically on the server?

Comment: @ThorDozer can you give more detailed example?